# Handle keyboard interruption and file writing

Tags: python

I have an application which monitors some data from web and write files almost every second. This application runs 24/7, but sometimes I have to turn it off. I use a keyboard interrupt exception to stop the app when I want, but once in a while the application does not finish the file writing and I got a corrupted file. What make me fix the file so as to get the app working properly when I turn it on again.

This is a piece of the code:

```
while True:
    try:
        conns = [http.client.HTTPSConnection(C.REQUEST_HOST) for k in range(C.num_coins)]

        for k in range(C.num_coins):
            conns[k].request("GET", C.REQUEST_PATH_TICKER.format(C.coin_types[k]))

        responses = [conns[k].getresponse().read() for k in range(C.num_coins)]
        responses_json_new = [
            json.loads(responses[k].decode(), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
            for k in range(C.num_coins)
        ]
        responses_json_new = [responses_json_new[k]["ticker"] for k in range(C.num_coins)]

        for k in range(C.num_coins):
            if responses_json_new[k]["last"] != responses_json_old[k]["last"]:

                date_ticker = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
                    int(responses_json_new[k]["date"])
                ).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

            with open(files_path[k] + date_ticker + ".json", "a") as f:
                json.dump(responses_json_new[k], f)
                f.write("\n")

            responses_json_old[k] = responses_json_new[k]
            print(
                out.format(
                    C.coin_types[k],
                    float(responses_json_new[k]["vol"]),
                    float(responses_json_new[k]["last"]),
                    datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
                        responses_json_new[k]["date"]
                    ).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                )
            )

        currentDate, files_path = updateFilePath(currentDate, files_path)
        time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nInterrupted!\n")
        for k in range(C.num_coins):
            if conns[k]:
                conns[k].close()
        sys.exit()
    except Exception as e:
        print("\nERROR:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        ut.exception_log(e, traceback.format_exc())
        ut.close_waiting(conns, wait=30)
        continue

    finally:
        for k in range(C.num_coins):
            if conns[k]:
                conns[k].close()
```

I need some suggestions on how can I handle this.

Thanks all!

Comment: How are you writing the file? If you're using one `.write()` call per one write, (optionally) followed by a `.flush()` call, there shouldn't be problems.

Comment: I use `.dump` to write the json file and `.write` too. Is it still work with `.dump`?

Comment: Make sure in your `KeyboardInterrupt` when you Ctrl+C you are properly `.close()`ing the file.  You have an `if` statement there which might be sometimes ignored, causing the file to remain open and therefore unable to be opened (unless you close python and reopen).  I'd put the `.close()` right before the `sys.exit()`

Comment: @J0hn OP is using `with` blocks for file access, so that's not necessary. They clean up the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.dump()` may (apparently) write the output in several chunks, if it's suitably large.

You'll want to use `.dumps()` to encode into a JSON string first, then `.write()` that to a file.

To prove that output may be written in multiple chunks, let's fire up `strace` in a Docker container and see what gets `write()`d.

```
(host) $ docker run -it ubuntu:18.04 bash
# apt install strace python3
# cat > ex1.py

import json, sys
payload = [[x] * x for x in range(5, 10)] * 250
json.dump(payload, sys.stdout)

# strace python3 ex1.py >/dev/null

(uninteresting lines redacted)
write(1, "[[5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6"..., 8194) = 8194
write(1, ", 6, 6], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], "..., 8194) = 8194
write(1, "], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8], [9,"..., 8194) = 8194
write(1, "[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9], [5,"..., 4168) = 4168

# cat > ex2.py

import json, sys
payload = [[x] * x for x in range(5, 10)] * 250
pl2 = json.dumps(payload)
sys.stdout.write(pl2)

# strace python3 ex2.py 

(uninteresting lines redacted)
write(1, "[[5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6"..., 28750) = 28750
```